# It doesn't display message if room is valid or not

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Please look at this create_session.php application: [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php)

When you open the application you will see a CourseId textbox. Type in 'info101' in the textbox then click submit.

It should display all of the features below. Don't type anything in, click on the "Prepare Questions" button at the bottom. You should see a lot of red messages. This is the validation stating what you need to do for each form input.

Now fill in all of the features but for the "Room" Textbox, please enter in "CN10/10". This is an incorrect value. After all details are filled then click on the "Prepare Questions" button, all the red messages should go but it should of displayed a message under the "Room" textbox as the value is incorrect, but no message is dislayed. It should of displayed the message "This Room is Invalid".

Now if you type in the correct value in the "Room" textbox 'CW5/10' and click on the "Prepare Questions" button, then it should show no message (which it does because I believe it is not using the Json correctly), but also a confirmation box should appear but this also doesn't happen.

So what my question is that why is it not doing what it is suppose to do for the room textbox. Why are the messages not appearing for the room textbox and when all features are correctly entered in, why is it not showing the confirmation box?

Below is the relevant code (not whole code,, just important code)

```
   function postback(callback){
        if(validation()){
            $.getJSON(
       '/u0867587/Mobile_app/create_session.php',
                {"room_no":$("#room").val()},
                function(json){
                    $("#roomAlert").html(json.msg);
                    callback(json.msg);
            });
        }
    } // should show message from php if room is valid or not

                 function showConfirm(){

             var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards your Session." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );

             if (confirmMsg==true)
             {
             submitform();   
         }
    }

<form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">

<p><strong>10: Room:</strong> <input type="text" id="room" name="roomChosen" value="<?php echo $roomChosen; ?>" />
<br/><span id="roomAlert"></span></p>      <!-- Enter Room here-->    

<p><strong>11: </strong><input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;"/></p>  
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['prequestion'])) {
    $roomquery = "
                 SELECT Room
                 FROM Room
                 WHERE
                 (Room = '".mysql_real_escape_string($roomChosen)."')
                 ";

    $roomnum = mysql_num_rows($roomresult = mysql_query($roomquery));
    mysql_close();

    if($roomnum ==0){
        $msg = "This Room is Invalid";
    } else {

        $msg = "";
    }

    $d = array("msg" => $msg);
echo json_encode($d);

} // checks to see if room value in textbox matches any value in database or not

?>

         <script type="text/javascript">

function myClickHandler(){ 
     if(validation()){ 
        postback(function(message) { 
            if (message == "") 
                showConfirm(); 
        }); 
     } 

} 


// if there is no validation errors and json message == "" (this message is displayed if there is match in database for room), then show confirmation box.

</script>
```

There is nothing wrong with the Sql. The name of the table is "Room" but the name of the field is also known as "Room". I have working sample of having a valid or invalid room in the room.php file [application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/room.php) , it just doesn't work in my create_session.php file. Again test it by typing in 'CW5/10' for valid room and anything else for invalid room

Comment: I think first argument in getJSON function is the backend file name to be called..which u r missing

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the file url in the get Json but it still does the same thing.

Comment: I know this does not fix your problem but have you considered using a dropdownlist or some other control that forces people to select a room rather than type it manually. It will save you from having to validate and in my opinion it will make it easier for users. Just a thought.

Comment: also what is the CW 5 part, is that a building code? If that is the case would it not be better to have at least a field for building and one for room, and have people select a building and then show all available rooms for that building to be selected.

Comment: Problem with drop down list is that there are loads of rooms, it will make the drop down list huge. There must be like 200 rooms

Comment: Oh wait I see, so you say let the user first choose a building and then allow the user to select only those rooms which are in that building

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your SQL request.
You should probably check the Room.id or Room.name, not just the Room, which seems to be your table name. Try your request directly in phpMyAdmin.

[edit]
If the request is not good, you may have an error/warning from your php file and the response is not in JSON format

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Sql. The name of the table is "Room" but the name of the field is also known as "Room". I have working sample of having a valid or invalid room in the room.php file [link](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/room.php) , it just doesn't work in my create_session.php file. Again test it by typing in 'CW5/10' for valid room and anything else for invalid room

Comment: I'm sorry but, in your create_session... the page reloads. There is no ajax request. Try to stop events and return "false" in your submitclick function.